# How can I divide 2 identical objects of one type, 2 identical objects of second kind and 2 identical objects of third kind?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How can I divide $2$ identical objects of one type, $2$ identical objects of second kind and $2$ identical objects of third kind into $3$ groups such that each groups contains only two objects.

The answer is $5$.

I tried the following:

Assume that I have objects A,A,B,B,C,C.
I need to make three groups from these objects of size 2. 
Let us first do the calculation of the objects were distinct.

$6!/(2!×2!×2!×3!) $  which is equal to 15. Now some cases need to be eliminated. But I can't understand how can I eliminate them without actually making groups and ruling out identical cases.

Comment: Have you tried simply enumerating the possibilities?

Comment: Yes. But I need the logic so that I can solve it if the number of objects or groups is changed.

Comment: the way the site works, you'll get a much better response from people if you write out your thoughts and indicate where you're stuck.

Comment: Actually I have no idea from where I do I start. Its easy if the objects are distinct but for identical objects I got no idea.

Comment: Hint: try to work recursively.  Either your arrangement has duplicates (groups like $AA$) or it doesn't.  If it does, then you are down to fewer types of objects.  If it doesn't, then you have a "derangement", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: I tried it but I get stuck on identical things. How do I use combinations to take into account that some objects are identical?

Comment: Once again, I suggest editing your post to show your thoughts and efforts.  It is difficult to help when we have no idea what level you are at.